# Difference between Vertx and Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, architecture, spring-boot, vertx3

Vertx and Spring both can be used to build entire REST application with many features like metrics calculation, monitoring via JMX etx.

a) What is the difference between **Spring Boot** and **Vertx**?

b) I stumbled upon an article: http://keaplogik.blogspot.in/2015/11/spring-boot-vertx-microservice-tech.html.
It describes a techstack that mixes both **vertx** and **Spring Boot**, but being new to both have not been able to figure out the usage in the mentioned link.

I am currently working on a REST application project, so I wanted to pick the correct stack before diving in.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no correct (or incorrect) stacks, just stacks that fits your needs or not. In that case, either one is good. My personal preference goes for vertx, but you should try both and make your own opinion.

Both documentation is good, so take few hours on each, experiment, and choose based on your own experience.